# display PDF file into WinForms

Tags: winforms, pdf, xps

I am working on a C# .Net Windows application. Here I create report using Infragistics.Documents.Report and export to .pdf & .xps format. Here I want to bringthose 2 files(.pdf & .xps) into WinForms and display. How to bring saved .pdf & .xps file into win forms.

Answer (score 4):

Put a web browser control in your form and navigate it to the PDF / XPS file. Providing a PDF Reader is installed on your system it should work great.

Comment: But it can cause the adobe reader to block the view with it's menus

Answer (score 4):

You can also use:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

...

Process.Start("Foo.pdf");
```

This is equivalent to the user double-clicking on a PDF file and will launch whatever PDF reader is installed on the system.

Answer (score 1):

http://blog.paritor.com/SimonBlog_Archive.html

Article, that you need, named "Integrating WPF with Windows Forms". DocumentViewer control is the part of WPF, but you still can embed WPF into your app.