# Viewing PDF in Windows forms using C#

Tags: c#, winforms, pdf, pdfview

Is there any way to view PDF files in a Winforms tool? I've seen solutions such as converting the pdf file into images and showing them in an picture box. However, I am asking whether i can view the file as PDF. Is there any tool from adobe or from Microsoft that supports this?

Comment: This was answered in an WPF question so I don't know if it works, but it is for winforms...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55083/opening-a-pdf-in-wpf-application/55177#55177

Comment: Not all end-user computers will have Adobe Reader or some other PDF viewer (with a IE plugin) installed. So, you will need a native .NET control to display the PDF. Gnostice has a [PDF viewer control for .NET](http://www.gnostice.com/nl_article.asp?id=159&t=How_To_Create_A_PDF_Viewer_in_PDFOne_NET_v2_x "PDF viewer control for .NET") in the PDFOne component suite. Disclaimer: I work for this company.

Comment: interesting!! i already finished the project i was working on when i asked this question .. but i'm gonna try this for sure!! thx for the tip ;)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

you can use **System.Diagnostics.Process.Start** as well as **WIN32 ShellExecute function** by means of interop, for opening PDF files using the default viewer:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("SOMEAPP.EXE","Path/SomeFile.Ext");

[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("shell32. dll")]
private static extern long ShellExecute(Int32 hWnd, string lpOperation, 
                                    string lpFile, string lpParameters, 
                                        string lpDirectory, long nShowCmd);
```

Another approach is to place a **WebBrowser Control** into your Form and then use the *Navigate* method for opening the PDF file:

```
ThewebBrowserControl.Navigate(@"c:\the_file.pdf");
```

Comment: no he wants the windows form project he's doing hosting the reader , not launch it

Comment: Yes, as Saif said, I need to view the pdf file inside my application and not launch the PDF reader :)

Comment: Use the WebBrowser Control into your form.

Comment: yes i think i'll go with that .. thx ..

Comment: Did you able to show the pdf inside WebBrowser Control ? I am trying the same thing but the application doesn't open it inside control rather it launces the third party PDF viewer application to show the pdf.

Comment: @Soumyaansh were you able to fix the issue.As, I am facing the same problem.

Answer (score 31):

i think the easiest way is to use the Adobe PDF reader COM Component

1. right click on your toolbox & select "Choose Items"
2. Select the "COM Components" tab
3. Select "Adobe PDF Reader" then click ok
4. Drag & Drop the control on your form & modify the "src" Property to the PDF files you want to read

i hope this helps

Comment: how can i resize this control so that it does not consume the whole form but stil resize when the form resizes?

Comment: 1+ perfect this supposed to be answer :)

Comment: I have this com component on my development machine. Does it also work on machines that do not have Adobe installed?

Comment: It will not work on a machine that does not have Adobe PDF Reader installed. You will get "Class not Registered" exception. Related Post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4041659/comexception-0x80040154-class-not-registered-when-using-axacropdflib/17894788

Answer (score 11):

[display PDF file into WinForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920313/display-pdf-file-into-winforms)

[Displaying a pdf file from Winform.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220134/displaying-a-pdf-file-from-winform)

[displaying a pdf on a windows form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324601/displaying-a-pdf-on-a-windows-form)

[How to display PDF or Word's DOC/DOCX inside WinForms window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/511046/how-to-display-pdf-or-words-doc-docx-inside-winforms-window)

[Reading/Writing PDF Files in Visual C# Windows Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301158/reading-writing-pdf-files-in-visual-c-windows-forms)

Answer (score 3):

Web Browser control might work. http://ryanfarley.com/blog/archive/2004/12/23/1330.aspx

Also a bunch of pdf open source c# projects here
http://csharp-source.net/open-source/pdf-libraries

Comment: Just for viewing the IE browser control should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a59LvC6BOuk

Use the above link

```java
private void btnopen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK){
        axAcroPDF1.src = openFileDialog1.FileName;
    }
}
```