# File Upload in C# windows Application

Tags: c#, winforms

In my C# Windows application I want to upload a pdf file but in my toolbox I cannot find a FileUpload control.

How can I go about and uploading a pdf file in a C# windows application.?

regards

Comment: Do you mean choose the file or parse it?

Comment: How to add controls to Visual Studio ToolBox --> [Link](http://blogs.cametoofar.com/post/Adding-Controls-to-Visual-Studio-Toolbox.aspx)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After you put a OpenFileDialog control on your form, let's say that you click a button and:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
            if (result == DialogResult.OK) // Test result.
            {
            //Do whatever you want
            //openFileDialog1.FileName .....
            }
        }
```

it goes something like this :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use **OpenFileDialog** to get the filename of the file you need and then .NET **File** object to read data from the file. You might need a control being able to display a PDF file. Please read the following:

[Viewing PDF in Windows forms using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4504442/viewing-pdf-in-windows-forms-using-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

```
public string GetFile(OpenFileDialog pOFD)
{
    pOFD.Filter = "Excel Files|*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm";
    if (pOFD.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        return pOFD.FileName;
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you edit your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?