# Saving excel file in application folder and uploading the content to SQL Server using windows forms and C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel

I'm working on a simple application which needs to browse an excel file and upload it to SQL server and also copy the file to application folder. By using below code I'm able to do it in web. But there is no alternative for FileUpload tool in winforms. Below is the code I'm trying to replicate in windows forms.

```
protected void Upload(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Upload and save the file
    string excelPath = Server.MapPath("~/Files/") + Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
    FileUpload1.SaveAs(excelPath);

    string conString = string.Empty;
    string extension = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
    switch (extension)
    {
        case ".xls": //Excel 97-03
            conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel03ConString"].ConnectionString;
            break;
        case ".xlsx": //Excel 07 or higher
            conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel07+ConString"].ConnectionString;
            break;

    }
    conString = string.Format(conString, excelPath);
    using (OleDbConnection excel_con = new OleDbConnection(conString))
    {
        excel_con.Open();
        string sheet1 = excel_con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null).Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
        DataTable dtExcelData = new DataTable();

        dtExcelData.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[3] { new DataColumn("Id", typeof(int)),
            new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("Salary",typeof(decimal)) });

        using (OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" + sheet1 + "]", excel_con))
        {
            oda.Fill(dtExcelData);
        }
        excel_con.Close();

        string consString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(consString))
        {
            using (SqlBulkCopy sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(con))
            {
                //Set the database table name
                sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.tblPersons";

                sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Id", "PersonId");
                sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Name", "Name");
                sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Salary", "Salary");
                con.Open();
                sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(dtExcelData);
                con.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13377932/file-upload-in-c-sharp-windows-application

Comment: That topic is related with copying files , my question is how to copy the excel file and save the same to SQL server database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The replacement of FileUpload in WinForm is OpenFileDialog:

```
string excelPath = "";
using(OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog())
{
  ofd.Filter = "Excel(.xls)|*.xls|Excel(.xlsx)|*.xlsx|All Files (*.*)|*.*";
  ofd.Multiselect = false;
  var result = ofd.ShowDialog();
  if (result == DialogResult.OK)
  {
    excelPath = ofd.FileName;
  }
}
//... continue with your sql code
```

The code for uploading to sql server is still the same, you can use it also in winform. From the sample above, "excelPath" is in my sample "ofd.FileName"