# How to view pdf files without using adobe reader while making an apllication on c#

Tags: c#

I am making an apllication universal document viewer using visual studio 2010-framework 3.5. In this i want to open a pdf file, i have used PDFTextStripper and Pdfbox but i am unable to view the text in proper format. Can anyone please suggest me any other option to view the pdf files.

Comment: Plz put that what u tried means your code

Comment: Try the WebBrowser approach, described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4504442/viewing-pdf-in-windows-forms-using-c-sharp

Comment: Have a look at this <a href="http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2013/04/6-javascript-jquery-pdf-viewer-plugin.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+aspdotnet-suresh+%28Aspdotnet-Suresh.Com+Recent+Articles%29">Plugins</a>. Hope this helps

Comment: this article will help you to solve your problem. [PDF viewer](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37458/PDF-Viewer-Control-Without-Acrobat-Reader-Installe)

Comment: Just link not a answer?Do you expect me to write whole code for him?

Answer (score 0):

you can either write your own pdf parser based on structure doc published by adobe:
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference.html

or add a module. e.g.:
http://www.pdfsharp.net/MainPage.ashx
http://www.itextpdf.com/itext.php

I'd recommend writing your own code if you are about to develop an universal doc viewer as you may face legal issues otherwise if you publish(w/wo donate option) or sell your app
(IMHO: by not coding everything from scratch, it won't be *your* universal doc viewer anyway but a collection of 3rd party code)