# In ASP .NET is there a way to create a winform as a pdf viewer rather than using the browser?

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, asp.net-3.5

In ASP .NET is there a way to create a winform (or something of the sort) as a pdf viewer rather than using the browser?

I need to restrict print, url to pdf and right click to save as image or anything else. If I can do this through the browser, where can I find some sample code?

I understand there are hacks to get that PDF downloaded and PRINT SCREEN is another option as well as any image capture program. This is in a INTRANET site so these things I am aware of and not worried about. We just need to make it difficult for non tech employees.

The PDF's hold important reporting information that we do not want print and leave in there office anymore.

Anyone have sample code to achieve this or any tutorial or any leads to the direction I need to take to achieve this?

FYI, site in 3.5 and Webforms...upgrade to 4 or 4.5 has not been approved yet.

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Viewing PDF in Windows forms using C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4504442/viewing-pdf-in-windows-forms-using-c-sharp)

Comment: The viewing pdfs outside the browser part may be relatively difficult, since the only reason pdfs display in a browser normally is a plugin. I mean, you could zip them or something, if you think your users can deal with that. I'm sure there are other, better options, though, and can't give a complete answer for anything else.

Comment: I've seen this, but how would I make the connection from the site. Will a Linkbutton create this winform without having to install anything?

Comment: Do you recommend a way to approach what I am looking for or should I just create a winform and have the user use an exe to load PDF's?

Comment: Also, I've seen government sites use java to create this, is this a possible solution with an ASP .NET site and where could I find tutorials on how to create that?