# View PDF files in ActiveX object .NET

Tags: c#, winforms, pdf, activex

I'm using PDFCreator 2.1 COM object to display PDF files inside my Window Form.
So far I added the control to Form. But I can't find a way (method or property) of this object ( AxCPDFActiveDoc ) to open the file.
I know, some time ago, acrobat reader had once in their SDK a object that did that for us. The property called "src". But in this I cannot find anything related.

```
pdfViewer = new AxCPDFActiveDoc();
pdfViewer.Height = this.Height - this.ficheiroBindingNavigator.Height - this.ficheiroBindingNavigator.Top - 25;
pdfViewer.Top = this.ficheiroBindingNavigator.Height - this.ficheiroBindingNavigator.Top;
pdfViewer.Left = Convert.ToInt32(this.Width * 0.2) - 50;
pdfViewer.Width = Convert.ToInt32(this.Width * 0.5);
this.Controls.Add(pdfViewer);
```

I have searched here http://docs.pdfforge.org/pdfcreator/latest/en/com-interface/ but nothing really related to ActiveX on Windows Forms.

Comment: PDFCreator enables you to create documents. To display them you need to see other options. E.g. [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4504503/115272) question

Comment: I've managed a way using web browser.

Answer (score 1):

Try another library: [pdfium.net sdk](http://pdfium.patagames.com) for example

You can install it through nuget
**Install-package pdfium.net.sdk**

Next place the control on form and use somthing like folow:

```
//Open and load a PDF document from a file.
pdfViewer1.LoadDocument(@"c:\test001.pdf");
```

to show PDF document