# View PDF File using Windows Form C# from Remote URL

Tags: c#, winforms, pdf

I'm looking for a solution , I want to view a pdf file on a windows form C# from a remote server / url.

Is this doable?

Comment: Yes, it is doable

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4504503/43846

Comment: [WebView2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/) can show PDF content without any plug-in. That's all you need. -- This Control replaces the old WebBrowser Control; works in Windows 7+ Systems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out. I'm using the [PDF Viewer](https://www.devexpress.com/products/net/controls/winforms/pdf-viewer/) control by DevExpress to display PDF documents within the app.

```
using System.Net;

string Url = "YOUR_URL";
using(WebClient client = new WebClient()) {
    using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(client.DownloadData(Url))) {
        pdfViewer1.LoadDocument(ms);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whilst using windows you should get the most consistent support using the native PDF engine which from Windows 7 (however depreciating as EOL) to 11 is MSEdge this can be integrated into WebView 2

[image]
and the best place to see starter and example code is at

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/code-samples-links#sample-code-for-get-started-guides

the github location is

https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Samples